# colorRampPalette in R

Tags: r, color-scheme

Can someone let me know the various colors which produced the excellent color mix in the 4-panel plot on this link:?

http://www.enr.gov.nt.ca/state-environment/13-projected-trends-temperature-and-precipitation-arctic

I need the color ramp on the right of the plot for precipitation.

I tried something like:

```
col=colorRampPalette(c( "red3","orange","gold1", "yellow", "lightskyblue","steelblue3", "royalblue3", 
                                                                                            "darkblue","darkblue"))(30))
```

but could not get it right. A list of colors in R is found here:

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf

Many thanks.
AZ.

Comment: If you only want a few colors you don't want colorRampPalette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify the colors using the [Eyedropper Tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Eyedropper) in Firefox, although it's a bit tedious. As you can see below, the actual palette is close but not quite the same as the Color Brewer palette.

```
actual <- c('#2F2C62', '#42399B', '#4A52A7', '#59AFEA', '#7BCEB8', '#A7DA64',
            '#EFF121', '#F5952D', '#E93131', '#D70131', '#D70131')
library(colorRamps)
barplot(cbind(1:11,1:11),beside=TRUE,names=c("actual","brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')"),
        col=c(rev(actual),brewer.pal(11,"RdYlBu")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks very close to the color scheme called 'RdYlBl' from RColorBrewer.

Here is how it looks like:

```
require('RColorBrewer')
display.brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')
```

[image]

(to use it: `brewer.pal(11,'RdYlBu')`)